# Windows 10 Emulator - XDE Parameters .. Where are they

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have Visual Studio 2013 professional edition installed on Windows 10 64 bitPRO. So far the Windows Phone 8 Apps  used to create, launch and debug fine.

Then I went ahead and downloaded Windows Phone 10 version emulators to visual studio 2013. it actually created some new Emulator entries (visible on Debug menu now).

However, when I launch the Windows phone 10 image from Visual studio, i get an error below

```
============================

[Window Title]
XDE.exe

[Content]
The VHD file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86%\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.10240.0\Flash.vhd does not exist.

[Close]
Little more troubleshooting indicated that the XDE tool is not able to resolve this environment variable %CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86% somehow.
```

Full Command was below

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1\XDE.exe" /name "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.myuser" /displayName "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd" /video "480x800" /memsize 512 /diagonalSize 4 /language 409 /bootlanguage 409 /creatediffdisk "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\8.1\dd.480x800.512.vhd" /snapshot  /fastShutdown
```

When I tried to run this command with resolved variable name, XDE launched fine @ individually @.  (make sure you launch via Command Prompt; Windows Run prompt does work for some reason).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\XDE.exe" /name "Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.myuser" /displayName "Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.10240.0\Flash.vhd" /video "480x854" /memsize 512 /diagonalSize 4 /language 409 /bootlanguage 409 /creatediffdisk "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.10240.0\dd.480x854.512.vhd" /snapshot  /fastShutdown
```

The Question is. Where are these parameters Stored for XDE .. i.e. , From where Visual STudio picks up these parameters and passes on to XDE ? ? 
FYI. I have see suggested Windows 10 emulator issues, none of those match my problem. Searching on Bing / Google doesn't render much info too . 
Any clues, it would help me keep Windows 10 development using Visual Studio 2013